# using a shell script how do I find a word in a document that has a specified number of characters?

Tags: shell, awk, grep, gawk

I have a word in a document that is 10 characters long and I wish to first find it then replace it with a 5 character word. What would be the most efficient way to do this with a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have given so little information, I will make up my own parameters

```
$ cat foo.txt
The quick brown fox jumps over the obligatory dog.

$ sed 's/obligatory/happy/' foo.txt
The quick brown fox jumps over the happy dog.
```

Comment: could I use a command to to find obligatory? specifically if example.txt file contains 10 character word then replace?

Comment: @anubie sed IS a command. What exactly is it you're trying to do? The above command does have a couple of possible issues because it will find words that are parts of other words (e.g. it will match "the" in "then" and not just a standalone "the") and it's doing an RE match instead of a string comparison but you really need to post some sample input/output to help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

this sed one-liner will do the replacement on the first 10-chars word:

```
sed -r 's/\b\w{10}\b/55555/'
```

same example:

```
kent$ echo "The quick brown fox jumps over the obligatory dog."|sed -r 's/\b\w{10}\b/55555/'
The quick brown fox jumps over the 55555 dog.
```